# How to check if a tensor is on cuda or send it to cuda in Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, tensor

I have a tensor

`t = torch.zeros((4, 5, 6))`

How to check if it is on gpu or not, and send it to gpu and back?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[From the pytorch forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-can-i-know-if-a-variable-is-a-cuda-varialbe/8460)

use `t.is_cuda`, `t.cuda()`, `t.cpu()`

```
t = torch.randn(2,2)
t.is_cuda  # returns False
t = torch.randn(2,2).cuda()
t.is_cuda  # returns True
t = t.cpu()
t.is_cuda  # returns False
```

When passing to and from gpu and cpu, new arrays are allocated on the relevant device.

Answer (score 1):

@Gulzar only tells you how to check whether the tensor is on the cpu or on the gpu. You can calculate the tensor on the GPU by the following method:

```
t = torch.rand(5, 3)
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
t = t.to(device)
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question and correct answers, but why not use

`print(tensor.get_device())`, as mentioned [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.get_device.html)?

This returns 0 if tensor is on GPU, and -1 if on CPU.